# What kind of techniques that I can use to see which type of of entries in the dataset became more popular lately(over a time-span)?

Tags: data-mining, data-analysis

This is for my school project. I've been digging the internet in to find a solution that is backed-up really well but I couldn't find a metric that makes sense.

I have a dataset, that has objects say: ['A', 'B', ... 'E'], and I have how many transactions that has been done to buy these objects and when (with all timestamps) over a year.

Now I need to find which objects became more and less popular lately, so the company would produce more or less number of those objects to optimize the profits. I don't have the number of objects in the inventory as well. Since there are 1500 objects I cannot really make a visualization to have an overall view. Things that came to mind:

1. Compare the mean number of sales per month for the first 3/4 of the year and the mean number of sales per month for the last 1/4 of the year.
2. Calculate the standard deviation for the whole period in the number of sales and compare the mean of the last 1/4 of the year to see if it's above or below standard deviation. If so, how many standard deviations away is the value that is being checked.

I was wondering if there is another more sophisticated solution for this problem, or if my solutions are good enough - if so which one is better. Should I use both maybe?

Comment: Why not simply look at the numer of transactions for product $x$ relative to all transactions in a period and plot all the "market shares" over time?

Comment: That's actually a quite good idea that I couldn't think of, thanks!